# Matlab : Conceptual difficulty in How to create multiple hash tables in Locality sensitive Hashing

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor, locality-sensitive-hash

The key idea of Locality sensitive hashing (LSH) is that neighbor points, **v** are more likely
mapped to the same bucket but points far from each other are more likely mapped to different buckets. In  using Random projection, if the the database contains N samples each of higher dimension d, then theory says that we must create k randomly generated hash functions, where k is the targeted reduced dimension denoted as `g(**v**) = (h_1(v),h_2(v),...,h_k(v))`. So, for any vector point **v**, the point is mapped to a k-dimensional vector with a g-function. Then the hash code is the vector of reduced length /dimension k and is regarded as a bucket. Now, to increase probability of collision, theory says that we should have L such g-functions `g_1, g_2,...,g_L` at random. This is the part that I do not understand.

Question : How to create multiple hash tables? How many buckets are contained in a hash table?

I am following the code given in the paper `Sparse Projections for High-Dimensional Binary Codes` by Yan Xia et. al  [Link to Code](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/)

In the file `Coding.m`

```
dim = size(X_train, 2);
R = randn(dim, bit);

% coding
B_query = (X_query*R >= 0);
B_base = (X_base*R >=0);
```

`X_query` is the set of query data each of dimension d and there are 1000 query samples; `R` is the random projection and bit is the target reduced dimensionality. The output of `B_query` and `B_base` are `N` strings of length `k` taking 0/1 values. 
Does this way create multiple hash tables i.e. `N` is the number of hash tables? I am confused as to how. A detailed explanation will be very helpful.

Comment: I apologise for the downvote, but this is the third question of yours I've found that has had substantial edits made to it after an answer is received. As I said on another answer, please broadly avoid doing this at all, but if you need to on rare occasions, please add a justification in the edit remarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to create multiple hash tables?

LSH creates hash-table using (amplified) hash functions by concatenation:

g(p) = [h<sub>1</sub>(p), h<sub>2</sub>(p), · · · , h<sub>k</sub> (p)], h<sub>i</sub> ∈<sub>R</sub> H

`g()` is a hash function and it corresponds to one hashtable. So we map the data, via `g()` to that hashtable and with probability, the close ones will fall into the same bucket and the non-close ones will fall into different buckets.

We do that `L` times, thus we create `L` hashtables. Note that every `g()` is/should most likely to be different that the other `g()` hash functions.

Note: Large k ⇒ larger gap between P<sub>1</sub>, P<sub>2</sub>. Small P<sub>1</sub> ⇒ larer L so as to find neighbors. A practical choice is L = 5 (or 6). P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub> are defined in the image below:

[image]

> How many buckets are contained in a hash table?

Wish I knew! That's a difficult question, how about `sqrt(N)` where `N` is the number of points in the dataset. Check this: [Number of buckets in LSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171834/number-of-buckets-in-lsh)

> The code of Yan Xia

I am not familiar with that, but from what you said, I believe that the query data you see are 1000 in number, because we wish to pose 1000 queries.

`k` is the length of the strings, because we have to **hash the query** to see in which bucket of a hashtable it will be mapped. The points inside that bucket are potential *(approximate) Nearest Neighbors*.

Comment: Thanks once more. THe part that is unclear is the number of hash codes, L which become the number ofhash tables. I seem to be missing on what is L. If 2 symbols are used 0 and 1 then how does one choose L?

Comment: In the code by Yan Xia, I do not see how they create L hash tables. THe Querydata are 1000 samples of 960 dimension. So, how is this connected to L?

Comment: The number of hash codes is `k`. `L` is the number of the hash functions `g()`. As mentioned in my answer @SKM, L is usually 5 or 6, it's not a function of `k`, is that is what you mean. One query is related to `L`, only in the fact that it hashed `L` times, one for each `g()` hash function.

Comment: Can you please mention the reason why L = 5 or 6? Based on my understanding from your explanation, if Number of Hash tables = Number of g() functions, then if k =2 is the reduced dimensionality,then I should have the following hash codes g1 = (01); g2 = (00); g3 = (10);g4=(11). i.e., 2^k combinations, each combination is a hash table. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: @SKM `L` can be more (or even less) than 5 or 6. However, **in practice**  it is said that LSH works well with `L` equal to 5 or 6. I do not know if `k` is called "reduced dimensionality". However, in your example, you are correct, i.e. for `L` = 4, we would have 4 hashtables, each one with the `g()` functions you mentioned.

Comment: One last Question, will be greatful for your insights. If there are N data points, then will there be L hash tables / hash codes of string length k for each data point? So, in total will there be N*L hash tables? From the example in my commen it seems that longer the hash code, more are the hash tables since L = 2^k where k is the length of the hash code.

Comment: @SKM **no**. The hash tables are `L`. So the number of hashtables is *not* a function of `k` or `N`. `k` modifies the length of the hash function `g()`. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: If possible, could you please provide a code snippet in Matlab showing how to create L hash tables for LSH using random projection ? This will help to get a better picture of your explanation in your answer. In hte Question that I posted, the output of B_query is 1000 points each of length bit representing 1000 hash codes.

Comment: I haven't wrote Matlab for a long @SKM, sorry. Nevertheless, that's another question, so you might want to post a new question! :)